# How to POST form in ASP.NET to another page just like HTML post?

Tags: asp.net, .net, post, webforms

I want to POST a form using ASP.NET. How can I do this?

I am new to ASP.NET. In PHP I used `<form>`'s `method` attribute, like this:

```php
<form method="POST" action="..."></form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code will be useful in case of link button

```
<asp:LinkButton 
  ID="Button1" 
  PostBackUrl="~/target.aspx"
  runat="server"
  Text="Submit" />
```

For simple button

```
<asp:Button 
      ID="Button1" 
      onClick="targetPage"
      runat="server"
      Text="Submit" />
```

Here target page is an event and for it you have to do C sharp coding. 
You should use following code in "targetpage" event:

```
Response.Redirect("target.aspx");
```

Answer (score 3):

See this Snippet Code:

```
<asp:Button 
  ID="Button1" 
  PostBackUrl="~/TargetPage.aspx"
  runat="server"
  Text="Submit" />
```

[How to: Post ASP.NET Web Pages to a Different Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx)

---

You might be also interested in getting the posted page variables as follow:

```
   public string UserName
   {
      get { return this.tbUsername.Text; }
      set { this.tbUsername.Text = this.sUsername; }
   }
```

And in the new Page Use:

```
 string sPostedUserName = (string)PreviousPage.UserName;
 //  you must first get a strongly typed reference to the source page
 <%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/login.aspx" %>
```

To get more into this see [Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)

There are too many ways of reading the posted variables like Query String:

```
 string prevPageVar  = Request.QueryString["MyVariable"];
```